# Android marshmallow fingerprint

Tags: android, fingerprint

I'm developing  an app to store multiple fingerprints in database and authenticate it. My question is:

1. is it possible  to store multiple fingerprint? If so is there a specific function?
2. for storing the fingerprint I was thinking of using sqlite database. Is there any database which can be used to store?

Please help me find a solution, thank you.

Comment: Sorry but you can't store fingerprint data in any form with you.....

Answer (score 1):

you cannot store any fingerprint in any device, you can just access if any fingerprint is stored on device.
for more details you can check this, there is also a sample provided for accessing the fingerprints.
[click here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication)